# How to display message for incorrect captcha

Tags: java, html, extjs, captcha, recaptcha

I was searching everywhere but no results(maybe I didn't know what to search).My problem is to display a message for the incorrect captcha solution like this(marked with red):

[image: Example Pic]

The captcha is displayed using an ExtJs panel:

```
{
    xtype:'panel',
    id:'reCaptcha-panel',
    html:'<div id="recaptcha"></div>',
    width:325,
    height:130,
    border:false,
    listeners:{
       afterrender:function(){
             Recaptcha.create(apiKey,
                              Ext.getDom('recaptcha'),
                              {
                                  theme : 'blackglass',
                                  lang:'en',
                                  callback: Recaptcha.focus_response_field
                              });
      }
   }
}
```

The panel is inside an ExtJs form(the script is included in a .html) and everything here works.On the server-side the captcha solution is checked using a java HttpURLConnection post request on google's servers which returns "incorrect-captcha-sol" only when the client's solution is incorrect.I need to know what to do for showing the message as in the picture above.

Comment: You have the callback there! Are you asking how to display something?

Answer (score 0):

When you get a response that captcha is wrong you just need to write below line.

```
Ext.get('recaptcha').dom.innerHTML = 'Incorrect Captcha..!';
```